# How to plotmeans of a group conditional on a variable

Tags: r

Basically right now I have a graph that displays the mean of one of my variables by year. I want to get two mean lines of that variable: one for when another variable in my frame = 0 and one for when it = 1 on the same plot.

Right now this is what I have:

```
library(gplots)

plotmeans(x ~ year, data = df, frame = FALSE,
      mean.labels = TRUE)
```

This currently works for just giving me the mean of x by year with no conditional. However, I want two lines one for the graphed mean of x when for example y=0 and one for the graphed mean of x when y=1 all by year still on the x axis.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. And you have `frame` and `y`? Both binary variables?

Comment: frame is not a variable. It is a modifier for the plot. I figured out the solution thanks to your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `gplots::plotmeans` accepts only one variable on the RHS of the formula argument. The trick is to use `interaction` between the variables of interest.

First, make up a data set.

```
set.seed(1234)    # Reproducible results

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(210), 
                 y = rbinom(210, 1, 0.5), 
                 year = rep(2017:2019, 70))
```

Now the graphs.

```
library(gplots)

plotmeans(x ~ interaction(year, y, sep = " y = "), data = df, 
          mean.labels = TRUE, digits = 2, 
          connect = list(1:3, 4:6))
```

[image]

```
plotmeans(x ~ interaction(y, year, sep = " "), data = df, 
          mean.labels = TRUE, digits = 2, 
          connect = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6))
```

[image]